React Native not recognizing Apple Health Kit
I keep getting this error when I try to initialize : (NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Warning: TypeError: _reactNativeHealth.default.getAuthStatus is not a function (it is undefined).
Please let me know if you have a solution! I followed the video step by step and am getting this error. I have an iOS folder created in my project that was created through downloading the package, made sure that package.json has  'expo start --dev -client', app.json has the react native plug-in. Here is my code:
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Value from './src/components/Value';
import RingProgress from './src/components/RingProgress';
import appleHealthKit, { HealthKitPermissions } from 'react-native-health';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const permissions: HealthKitPermissions = {
  permissions: {
    read: [appleHealthKit.Constants.Permissions.Steps],
    write: [],
  }
}
export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    appleHealthKit.getAuthStatus(permissions, (err: any, results: any ) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('error getting Healthkit auth status: ', err)
      }
      if (results) {
        console.log('results: ', results)
      }
    });

  },[]);
...

